# Finding similar strings

Tags: java, c#, string, split, similarity

I am aware how to find similar strings but this situation is tricky

SUPPOSE I have the following strings:

```
Xyz , rmz 2014-R1
Xyz 2014 - R1
Xyz , rmz 2014-r2
```

They all look similar right? But I only want my program to return strings with similar numbers

Here is what I want my code to return:

```
Xyz , rmz 2014-R1
Xyz 2014 - R1
```

Since the third string had 2014-R2 (It is considered a different quarter of a year) , I do not want my code to return that.

One approach I can think about is split and collect all the digits. If its similar and the digits match it matches?

This is to remove duplicates, any tips? I might have to do it manually but thinking of creative ways to address this situation.

Comment: Regex split on nonalphanumeric characters to piecewise comparison

Comment: You could use regex...

Comment: Do they have some identifier? Like do tehy start at a particular index or after only a comma ',' ?

Comment: str.contains("2014") && str.contains("R1") ... something like this

Comment: try using this regex pattern
(Xyz)*.+(2014)*.R1
you can use sublime to test this pattern using find tool and selecting regexp search (Ctrl+F)

Comment: Just saying that just the numbers are same. Sometimes the data is weird like just 2012,1 so no order

Comment: You should give more information, if all the strings are something like `.{0,100}2014.{0,2}-.{0,2}[rR][0-9]`, it should be easy.

Comment: I don't control the strings. The strings just have same name and quarter of year (indicated by 1,2,3,4). Its a database not something not just two strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to search for the pattern dddd-rd:

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
      String line = "Xyz , rmz 2014-r2";
      String pattern = "\\d\\d\\d\\d-.\\d";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
}
```

You can check each line for this pattern then check to see if it is the year/quarter you want...

If you want to search for a specific year and quarter you can do like this:

```
String pattern = "2014-r2";
```